# Jquery datepicker and compute function

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have some problem with jquery datepicker and compute function.
When I fill every field the function calculating the right value in "total day" field, but when I change date to another the "total day" value didn't calculate.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/3Upet/

Comment: Try: `$('input#date_from').on('blur', compute);` and `$('input#date_to').on('blur', compute);`

Comment: it works, but only on the second change in the same date field

Comment: to be faster remove my previus test and add `compute()` function inside `onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {` after the if statement

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. After change i have to change the hour or minute field to calculate

Comment: What's do not work? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axqyR/)

Comment: Example http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/3Upet/1/

Comment: see my fiddle in previus comment

Comment: I missed it, sorry and Thanks Man! :)

Comment: added as answer, happy to be useful ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add compute function inside onSelect:

```
    $('#date_to').datepicker("option","maxDate",rent_date_to);      
        }
        compute(); //Add compute
    }
```

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axqyR/)

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker is not triggering the 'change' event. Either run your compute() function in the onSelect event as well as binding it to change on the other inputs - or manually trigger the change event.

To manually trigger change, I would add it into the onSelect callback- bring the second param (datepicker instance) through:

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate, inst )
```

which we need to target the relevant input at the end of your callback for onSelect:

```
inst.input.trigger('change');
```